# Breakpoint fails to bind in BackgroundThread

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2015

I have a background thread running that handles a connection to a SQL database. The code looks like this:

```
    private static void Timer()
    {
        try
        {
            var list = RemindersRepository.GetReminders();
            foreach (var reminder in list)
            {
                if (reminder.EndDate < DateTime.Now)
                {
                    SendMessage(reminder);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

When I set a breakpoint at `var list...` then it catches that breakpoint. But  when I set it in the foreach then it fails. Why does it not continue after the initialization of the list?

Comment: What do you mean by 'fails'?  Are you sure the list actually has anything it?

Comment: What happens when you stop at the breakpoint at `var list...` and hit F10 to make the next step?

Comment: In catch block,are you getting any exception?

Comment: With 'fails' I mean that Visual Studio pops up a message saying 'The breakpoint failed to bind'. There are no exceptions. The list contains 3 items, as expected... When I hit F11 it just goes back to the  RemindersRepository.GetReminders() method, like it goes in a loop. Very weird